# How to open a corrupt XML file inside a ZIP archive

Tags: zip, xml

My work doc is corrupted and I know how to fix it, I just can't open the `document.xml` file because WinRAR is saying its corrupt. I can't get any repair tool to look in the zip file to repair the file. How can I repair the `.xml` from inside the zip, or how do I get the file out of the zip folder?

Just a little extra info: it's a 2010 word doc that got corrupted and I don't trust some of the tools on the web to fix the files. The error I get when I open the work doc is:

> An attribute value must not contain '<'.  Location: Part: /word/document.xml, Line: 2, Column: 1588862

How do I get a corrupt file out of a zip file? it's only the `document.xml` that is corrupt - none of the other files.

Comment: Restore the zip file from backups.

Comment: Is the doc or the zip file corrupted or both? I doubt WinRAR checking the consitency of the XML/doc file and an editor refusing to open it if it was not corrupted, so I'd say both.

Comment: @KarlRichter im not sure :/ When I try to get the file out of the zip it says the file is currupt and can't continue the process. I would guess the `document.xml` file. it's a `.docx` that's been opened as a zip.

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of the file and rename it "whatever.zip".

Extract the contents of the zip file.  Open the offending document.xml in the word directory, find the attribute that contains the illegal character, and either replace it (with `&lt;`) or remove it.  Save the file, rezip the directory, and rename the file with `.docx`.

Comment: i've done that, but i cant open the document.xml because its currupted.

Comment: You can't open it using a text editor?

Comment: no, because the docuement.Xml is in the .zip and i cant drag it out because it gives me an error saying the xml file is corrupted :/ can open in in the zip either.